# Неверное выполнение оператора if

Tags: java, android, авторизация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Создаю авторизацию в приложении. Схема простая: если пользователь ввел верные данные, то переходим на другое activity, если неверные, то выводим Toast с ошибкой. Данные, введенные пользователем сравниваются с таблицей пользователей в БД. Но несмотря на то, что условие в операторе if выполняется верно, программа переходит к блоку else. При выполнении программы по шагам видно, что условие проходит проверку.

**Функция, отвечающая за проверку в классе с БД:**

```
//проверяем существует ли пользователь для страницы авторизации
public String[] ExistLogin(String login, String password) {
    String username = "";
    String pass = "";
    try {
        Cursor c =  mDB.query(DB_TABLE_USERS, null, USERS_COLOMN_LOGIN + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(login)},null, null, null);
        if (c == null || c.getCount() == 0) {
            String arr[] = new String [2];
            arr[0] = username;
            arr[1] = pass;
            return arr;
        }
        else {
            Cursor c2 =  mDB.query(DB_TABLE_USERS, null, USERS_COLOMN_PASSWORD + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(password)},null, null, null);
            if (c2 == null || c.getCount() == 0){
                String arr[] = new String [2];
                arr[0] = username;
                arr[1] = pass;
                return arr;
            }
            else {
                c.moveToFirst();
                username = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(USERS_COLOMN_LOGIN));
                pass = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(USERS_COLOMN_PASSWORD));
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String arr2[] = new String [2];
    arr2[0] = username;
    arr2[1] = pass;
    return arr2;
}
```

**Activity с авторизацией:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText etLogin, etPassword;
Button btnLogin, btnRegisterLink;
TextView tvSiteLink;
DB db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    etLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLogin);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnRegisterLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterLink);
    tvSiteLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSiteLink);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // открываем подключение к БД
    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnLogin:
            String get[] = new String [2];
            get[0] = (etLogin.getText().toString());
            get[1] = (etPassword.getText().toString());
            String [] storedUser = db.ExistLogin(get[0],get[1]);
            if (storedUser.equals(get)){
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            }
            else {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Неправильный логин и/или пароль", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               etLogin.setText("");
               etPassword.setText("");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnRegisterLink:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
            break;
    }
    //закрываем подключение к БД
    db.close();
}
```

}

Comment: вы в предыдущем своем вопросе использовали мой ответ, и не отметили, как правильный. Причем использовали еще и неправильно

Comment: *Но несмотря на то, что условие в операторе if выполняется верно*

а как Вы это проверили?

Comment: По этому вопросу: Вы неправильно представляете себе, как работает метод equals() для массивов. Он сравнивает указатели.

Comment: А операция == тоже сравнивает указатели? С ней тоже не работает верно. При запуске программы по шагам студия пишет, что данные, введенные пользователем: "username" и "12345". Такие же строки она получает от функции проверки наличия пользователя в БД

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `if (c2 == null || c.getCount() == 0){` замените на  `if (c2 == null || c2.getCount() == 0){`
2. `storedUser.equals(get)` работает не так, как вы думаете. Он проверяет, совпадают ли ссылки у этих двух объектов. Они, естественно, не совпадают. 
   По-плохому: вам нужно проверять сначала совпадает ли длинна этих массивов, дальше, не содержат ли они null в своих элементах, и после этого сравнивать через equals:`storedUser[0].equals(get[0]) && storedUser[1].equals(get[1])`. По-хорошему - создайте класс `User`, у которого сделайте 2 поля - логин и пароль. Переопределите у этого класса метод `equals()`, и сделайте, чтобы этот метод сравнивал логин и пароль.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать